# WP application replacing another

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, monogame

I have now made two Windows Phone 8 applications based on the MonoGame template. My problem is that whenever I install either one of them then the other one is replaced. I do not understand this because they have different names and I have change both their GUIDs multiple times. What could possibly be causing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Haven't used MonoGame - maybe there is something in their system that causes problems. However, in normal conditions, Windows Phone apps do not replace other apps **unless** they have the same app ID (aka the GUID that you're talking about). You can have apps with the same name but different GUIDs, and both will live fine by each other.

Can you show what GUID you're replacing? Are you changing the manifest? Are the apps a part of the same solution?

Comment: I just noticed that I replaced the the GUID in the wrong place when you now mentioned the manifest.